# Signed in from multiple account is violation

Tags: freelance-websites

Mostly freelancing sites like elance not allowed users to make multiple accounts it is violation of their agreement but here is some case different which i want to discuss with you. I have good reputed elance profile all things were working great one day my friend come to my office he logged in elance from my computer using firefox and i was signin with chrome my friend posted a new job elance and also invite me. I respond him from my account to submit a proposal but i after few days i got a elance review notification according to that "see you may have signed up for more than one Elance account which is a violation of Elance policy. This policy is just one way to help ensure clients and freelancers know exactly who they are working with and it encourages trust in the marketplace."
After that i am unable to bid on jobs unable to see job description, elance is asking about the connection between two accounts so please let me know what should I reply to them is this violation of their agreement?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no answer regarding my question in whole community?

Comment: You don't have multiple accounts, right? So you just need to show you're different people. Submitting identification for both people and explaining the situation should be enough.

Comment: @Stacey they are still not willing to active both account even they are verified, they are saying just complete open jobs(this is due they want happy their clients not freelancer)

Comment: Properly structured paragraph breaks and text aides in users *wanting* to even read your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elance is very strict in preventing double accounts and fake jobs. Reply to them honestly and do ID verification if you haven't so far (they will ask you later on). Also ask your friend to do ID verification. I am sure that he was warned by Elance as well. Once they prove both identities, the account will unfreeze.

You cannot bid or view project because your account has been in suspended mode.

Next time be smarter and try to learn something about IP addresses and cookies. And in case more of you log to Elance from the same external IP (office LAN), immediately inform Elance about this before they suspend the account for review process.

Comment: "Once they prove both identities, the account will freeze" is this statement mean they will when we verify our identities they will remove our account permanently? if yes then why?

Comment: Sorry, I mean unfreeze. A typo.

Comment: thanks for your reply, how elance catch double account any idea?

Comment: IP, cookies and probably more undisclosed methods.

Comment: is this compulsory both would be verified because I have no control on other ID so how I can force other to verify?

Comment: I have no answer to that. Ask elance support.

Comment: You say the other person is your friend. If they ARE your friend, they will be willing to help you fix this. Also, isn't their account also frozen?

Comment: @Voxwoman yes his account also frozen and elance is not contacting with him.

Comment: @PeterMV I have read lot of stories like here http://elancehorror.blogspot.com/ most of the people never their account active.

Comment: @MayanKhan Well it depends what you did and how severe this is. They tried to cheat the system or wanted to be paid out of it. As simple as this. I don't believe their stories of being innocent and banned. Neither should you. Try, what can you lose. If they lock your account, open a new one and be smarter this time.

Comment: @MayanKhan That story is really horror story, but he also tried to cheat the system. I don't believe about his "petty money client" as it was himself.

Comment: They already taken my government ID and verified on that as I think on next time it is very hard to open new ID, what you suggest?

Comment: @MayanKhan I cannot suggest anything legal. But I guess you can ask your relative to help. We should not discuss about this any more.